# Geoserver - ImagePyramid plugin problem

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a huge Geotiff file , and i've tiled it ..
I've created the tiles using gdal_retile.py tool , but i'm getting the following error from Geoserver while linking the layer with the tiles folder : `Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: This plugin accepts only File, URL and String pointing to a file` any suggestion?

Comment: Did you explicitly set the SRS? Showing the gdal_retile line you are executing whould be very useful.

Comment: You should look into the logs and see if there is a Java stack trace in there around the time you configured the layer? I also agree showing the gdal_retile.py would help, along with a gdalinfo call on one of your files.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and in my case it was caused by GeoServer not having write permission for the pyramid data directory, i.e., the directory I passed to gdal_retile.py as the -targetDir argument.

The stack trace in the log included:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This plugin accepts only File, URL and String pointing to a file
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.<init>(ImagePyramidReader.java:182)
```

The message was misleading, though. The connection URL I passed was a valid file URL, but it specified a directory structure that was read-only for the `tomcat` user.

In my particular case, I had run gdal_retile.py with a sudo command and so the pyramid directory was owned by root. I was able to fix the problem by changing the directory's owner and group to `tomcat` with the command `chmod -R tomcat:tomcat <pyramid root dir>`.

This allowed the ImagePyramid plugin to:

- create a new directory named 0 under pyramid
- move all tiff files in pyramid into 0
- create an image mosaic in all sub-directories (shapefile index plus property file)
- create the root property file describing the whole pyramid structure

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the top level imagery into a directory with the name 0 (zero)? After making the tiles you need to do this additional step for it to work on Geoserver.

As described in the on the [Geoserver webpages](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html)

- move all tiff files in the root to a newly create directory 0
- create an image mosaic in all sub-directories (shapefile index plus property file)
- create the root property file describing the whole pyramid structure

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a newer Tomcat.

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4062 - for a discussion of what might cause this problem.

Comment: I tried to run under tomcat 7.0 , same issue happened

Comment: does the user running tomcat have write permissions to the data folder?

Comment: Yes , sure .. Also the action seems to be cutting in a step , because once i clicked Add layer , the root tiles moved to a new folder named 0 , so there's an action happening with no successful end